# Problem with populating JSONArray from database

Tags: java, android, json, rest

I'm trying to update my old application which is basically a shared shopping list. It was previously linked to my schools website and database, but I have reverse engineered it due to not having access anymore.
The app was originally created for sdk 23
Problem is it does not seem to populate the JSONArray using [this](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api) api.
Code goes as follows:

```
//MainActivity.java
@Override
    protected Long doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL itemListURL = new URL(itemList_URI);
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) itemListURL.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            int status = connection.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("HTTPS GET", "status " + status);
            if (status == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String responseString;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((responseString = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb = sb.append(responseString);
                }
                String itemData = sb.toString();
                itemArrayList = Item.createItemList(itemData);
                .......
//Item.java
//Create ItemList
public static ArrayList<Item> createItemList(String jsonItemsString)
        throws JSONException, NullPointerException {
    ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();

    JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(jsonItemsString);
    JSONArray jsonItemTable = jsonData.optJSONArray(TABLE_NAME)    
    for (int i = 0; i <= jsonItemTable.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonItem = (JSONObject) jsonItemTable.get(i);
        Item thisItem = new Item(jsonItem);
        itemList.add(thisItem);
    }
    return itemList;
}
```

The for-loop is throwing a NullPointerException, which leads me to beliveve the JSONArray is not populated.
here is an image of the url and the response:
[image: URL-Results]

So either the values can't be read, or the database connection fails(which I doubt, because there are no errors indicating it), but I have no idea how to verify this
Sorry for what might be a messy question. I have done any programming in almost 4 years, so a little rusty. I will happily provide any information needed.

Edit: Someone suggested a thread asking what a NullPointerException is, might hold the answer to my problem, but I know what a npe is, I just can't figure out why it's getting thrown

Update: D/HTTP GET: status 200, which should be "Ok"?
I logged the itemData String, and got this, so it can at least get the data:
[image]
Same with jsonItemsString:
[image]
Could it be the {"records": - Part which messes it up? It did not used to be there, but it seems updates to the api adds this.

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend using a library like retrofit for API calls. It will make things so much easier.  https://github.com/square/retrofit

Comment: Can you printf jsonItemsString so we can check the json content? The problem may come from here...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Can you debug, and check if are getting value inside jsonItemString and then with jsonData so that it would be easy to identify it!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found out where it went wrong.
All I did was swap

```
JSONArray jsonItemTable = jsonData.optJSONArray(TABLE_NAME);
```

With

```
JSONArray jsonItemTable = jsonData.getJSONArray("records");
```

In Item.java
No clue why it worked in my first version, but thank you to all who commented and got me on the right track!